# react material-ui how to override muibox-root

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, overriding

I want to override the MuiBox-root style for the whole application.According to the [official documentation](https://material-ui.com/customization/globals/#css) I need to identify the class:

[image]

And among other things I can override it:

[image]

But if I proceed this way, it just removes the styling. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The `createMuiTheme`, as said in the document, "change every single style injected by Material-UI into the DOM". So it will wipe out the old CSS and replace them with your CSS. If you only want to change some property and leave the rest untouched then maybe `makeStyles` is your answer

Comment: @kunquan I want to change the padding property only once

Comment: show the whole of the code

Comment: Yes you can do that with `makeStyles`. You can see how to use that by go to any component and choose to view the whole code. This method basically allow you to write CSS and won't completely wipe out the default CSS

Comment: @kunquan I can not get this working... it keeps rendering the same value

Comment: @assembler give it a green tick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do:

```
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const styles = {
  root: {
    padding: "10px"
  }
};

function App({ classes }) {
  return <yourelement  className={classes.root}>xyz...<yourelement/>;
}
export default withStyles(styles)(App);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sx` property on the `Box` component. For example:

```
<Box sx={{ padding: "10px" }}>
   <YourChildComponents/>
</Box>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say aim is to override `background` css field of root `background` css field.
Below are the steps

```
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
  },
});

export default function testFunction() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <Button className={classes.root}>Hook</Button>;
}
```

Hope this will help.